# Magento 1.9 Remove stock status from order confirmation email

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email, stock-status

I can't seem to find how to remove the stock status from the order confirmation (which goes to the client). We would like to remove it because we don't like to inform the client about it. I've already checked the stock status settings in the backend (System -> Catalogue -> Stock -> Backorders = Accept under the stock of 0 (not the one which includes informing the client).

Can somebody please send me in the correct direction on how to remove this? Please also see the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiBRI.jpg). I also tried to check the item's email template (under order) but I can't seem to find the exact rule where this gets inserted. Does it also seem that it's trying to 'add' it to the product name?

Thanks in advance! PS. I'm not a Magento pro, haha.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure it's not actually the product name (i.e. the product name doesn't include the stock text in other locations), you might want to check out the order items template in `/app/design/frontend/your/theme/template/email/order/items/default.phtml`

In `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/default.phtml` on line 31 it says 
`<strong style="font-size:11px;"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>`

In your version it'll probably have some mentioning of stock value.